# Remove leading zero in month in a date python in windows

Tags: python, windows

My string is: `Nov 05 2016 01:30:00PM`
I need to remove leading 0 of month and hour
the output should be like `Nov 5 2016 1:30:00PM`

Adding a hyphen between the % and the letter, you can not remove the leading zero windows..so I cannot use that option.

```
import time
from_date="2016-10-02T01:45:00"
conv=time.strptime(from_date,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
conDateTime = time.strftime("%b %d %Y %I:%M:%S%p",conv)
print conDateTime
day  = time.strftime("%d",conv).lstrip('0')
hour = time.strftime("%H",conv).lstrip('0')
conDateTime = conDateTime.replace(time.strftime("%d",conv), day)
conDateTime = conDateTime.replace(time.strftime("%I",conv), hour)
print conDateTime
```

Out put : Oct 2 216 1:45:00AM 
It removes 0 of month and year

```
conDateTime = conDateTime.replace(time.strftime("%d",conDateTime), day)
```

gives following error TypeError: argument must be 9-item sequence, not str

Comment: Please give more detail by adding what you've tried so far

Comment: Try this code `print time.strftime("%b %e %Y ", conv) + "{0:d}".format(conv.tm_hour) + time.strftime(":%M:%S%p", conv)
`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a simple way to do this. You need to convert the parts separately and then join them together. Here's one way to do that which works on Python 2 and Python 3.

```
import time

time_formats = ('%b', '%d %Y', '%I:%M:%S%p')

def strip_time(fmt, t):
    return time.strftime(fmt, t).lstrip('0')

from_date = "2016-10-02T01:45:00"
conv = time.strptime(from_date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
conDateTime = [strip_time(fmt, conv) for fmt in time_formats]
print(' '.join(conDateTime))
```

**output**

```
Oct 2 2016 1:45:00AM
```